# Communication between application windows and single popup window

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I have a web application running in one or more browser tabs/windows. I also have a SharedWorker, which is connected to every single one tab/window and is also communicating with some server over websocket. To this point everything works as expected and without any problems.

There, I also have a single popup window (opened automatically or with user interaction, it doesn't matter) with some SIP/WebRTC plugin. After it's opened, I can communicate with it over the same SharedWorker as everything else and that's OK.
SharedWorker also keeps (or, at least, is trying) information about every connected tab/window - based on `connect` event in worker and `beforeUnload` in every other tab/window. Not the best solution, but only one I found working.

Everything runs on the same domain, in the same location.

Now, **I can't** find **any** solution to:

- get the popup window handle from other tab/window than its opener, nor it's not possible to transfer handle to SharedWorker
- react to close of popup window every time, cause in some point that window worker port gets lost
- focus popup window from every other tab/window, cause there's no handle to it

Comment: couldn't the popup handle the communication with the sharedworker and receive events where it has to focus itself? Are you looking at a kind of observer pattern?

Comment: postMessage or window.opener....

Comment: @Icepickle calling `window.focus()` on popup doesn't work, it works only when called from opener, but...

Comment: @epascarello at some point there's no opener window available anymore.

Comment: ANd at the point you lose contact with said window.

Comment: Perhaps you should make the popup give an alert when it can't find the opener window anymore. That way, you would have a better idea of when that connection is lost.